# Как отправить письмо на почту с помощью Python используя гугл почту

Tags: python

Есть код отправляющий письмо с 1 адреса на другой. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно отправить письмо **через гугл аккаунт** а не через яндекс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так укажите параметры для гугла, в чём проблема?

Comment: посмотрите тут  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvAGL0EDLVY

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть в виде текста, а не скриншотом. и слово "дурачок" пишется через "о".

Comment: слово дурачёк написано дурачком :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для начала нужно поправить настройки вашего gmail-аккаунта

**Allow less secure apps: ON**

Адрес к настройке - [настройка ненадежных приложений](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4NdxzkRAjL68t7k0KaNuORO564QHNUr352UL4Q6hYX0G-DY0Xwo5HgJv63FtCsb9xPAc14Kenh8qKmGPeL24_wSPAIRjg)

Или используйте скрипт для доступа к аккаунту через API (поищите информацию в ресурсах гугла для разработчиков).

2. SMTP коннект:

```py
    self.port = 465
    self.smtp_server_domain_name = "smtp.gmail.com"
```